# Cygwin - setting up $PATH

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin

I've found it's really difficult to setup path variable. I've tried a lot of combinations but nothing works at all. My over 1h work results are [image] but as you see on screenshot (http://puu.sh/33n0X.png )

```
echo $PATH
```

give strange directory and

```
rm -rf k.txt
```

doesn't work at all. Does anyone has idea what is wrong there? I'm totally confused about it

Comment: What do you mean by "rm -rf k.txt doesn't work at all"? The `rm` command normally doesn't print anything if it successfully removed the file. Most of the directories you see in `$PATH` were set before you prepended your own directories to it.

Comment: What do you expect for your $PATH? Since you can use `rm`, I think your $PATH is already set up correctly.

Comment: Note that `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are the same directory in Cygwin, so only one of them needs to be in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something a little more "normal", you can suppress the current `PATH` being appended, and just build your own.

In your `~/.bash_profile`, put something to this effect

```
PATH=/bin
```

and if you want `System32` you can add it as well

```
PATH=/bin:${TMP%U*}windows/system32
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.path)